# Extract hour from a column of time

Tags: r

Currently I have a column with time in the format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss, (eg. 2015-10-10 04:10:45) and I wish to extract the hour possibly using `as.POSIXlt(x)$hour` where x is my column.

Unfortunately, this function is returning a vector full of 0's, but if I do something like `as.POSIXlt("2015-10-10 04:10:45")$hour` I receive `4` which is what I want.

How can I do this with the whole column?

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Did you mean `as.POSIXlt( myData$x )$hour` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was just doing the exact same thing on my dataset...

```
format(as.POSIXct(df$datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), format="%H:%M:%S")
#[1] "04:10:45"
```

Comment: This did the job, thanks.

Comment: @user3276768 can you explain how is this answer better than your attempt and what isn't working? `as.POSIXlt(c("2015-10-10 04:10:45", "2015-10-10 05:10:45", "2015-10-10 06:10:45"))$hour` works perfectly fine for a vector. From what you wrote you wanted an integer hour not a character string with minutes and seconds. I have no idea what's going on here.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I think he meant "`4` is NOT what I want"